# Select specific amount of rows from query

Tags: sql-server

I have this query below and I need to get specific amounts of rows from it also, like 100 rows. I also need to get the rows from a specific row count like from 100 to 200, from 200 - 300 etc. I have been experimenting with `ROW_NUMBER()` function without luck.

NB! Cannot us "offset 100 rows fetch next 100 rows only" because it only works in mssql 2012.

```
SELECT 
      Result.CaseCount,
      CaseID, 
      ChildCaseName,
      CPR,
      FirstName,
      LastName, 
      CustomerInfoID, 
      InstitutionName, 
      CaseDeadline, 
      [StatusName], 
      [StatusOwner] 
FROM ResultSelectorCTE, 
    (select count(*) as CaseCount FROM ResultSelectorCTE) AS Result
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Use `SELECT TOP 100 Column1, Column2 FROM Table`

Comment: note: when using "top", "limit" etc, you should always include an `order by` clause... otherwise: *which 100 are you selecting?*

Comment: Do you want to get X rows or get everything and also a row count? You tagged C# - do you want to get a count in your C# code or in the SQL query?

Comment: @OwenPauling Yes, I want to get x amount of rows. I should have specified that I need 100 rows from a specific point like for a paging functionality.

Comment: @Örvar that is an important additional requirement, which changes the solution - but see `OFFSET {n} ROWS FETCH NEXT {m} ROWS ONLY`

Comment: @MarcGravell You are right, I have edited the question now. I would love to use OFFSET {n} ROWS FETCH NEXT {m} ROWS ONLY but it does not work in mssql 2008 only in 2012 :(

Comment: @Örvar then... update to a version of SQL-Server that isn't many years behind? you can use row_number too, though; one moment (I'll update my answer); however, you should have mentioned that in the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I also need to get the rows from a specific row count like from 100 to 200, from 200 - 300 etc.

```
select Foo, Bar
from SomeTable
order by Blap
offset 100 rows fetch next 100 rows only
```

Or to do it with `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
select x.Foo, x.Bar
from (
    select Foo, Bar, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by Blap desc) as [Row]
    from SomeTable) x
where x.[Row] > 100 and x.[Row] <= 200
order by x.[Row]
```

Comment: Is there any way to get the count in there aswell?

Comment: @Örvar which count? if you mean the total number of rows, I would do that as a separate query: `select count(1) from SomeTable`

Comment: Yes, the total numbers of rows. I was just hoping it was possible to  get all the information needed in one call. I am working on a performance issue for a customer. Perhaps the if the "big" call was possible, it could possibly result in even worse performance insted making two calls to the database... Thanks for your help. I will be more precise next time I post a question.

Comment: I have not read about it yet, but I can imagien  that the count function is really really fast,

Answer (score 3):

MSSQL: `SELECT TOP 100 Result.CaseCount,...`

MYSQL: `SELECT  ... LIMIT 100;`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP X Result.CaseCount, CaseID, ChildCaseName, ...
```

Where X is your number.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select TOP 100 [column1],[column2].....FROM TABLE
```

but it will depends on the query you are giving.
If no `orderby` is there it will pull different result each time..